# Flickering issues when transitioning pages with textarea fields in Onsen UI / Phonegap

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, monaca

If I delete all the text area fields in a page, the transition is smooth, otherwise it flickers at the end of the transition. Onsen 1.3.0 / Monaca IDE.

Any ideas?

```html
<ons-list modifier="inset" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <ons-list-item class="item">
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="35px"> 
          <label class="checkbox item-title" ng-click="save($index, false)" style="padding-left:2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="project.done">
            <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark" style="margin-top: 0;"></div>
          </label>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <header style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom:8px;">
            <textarea ng-model="project.title" ng-blur="save($index, false)" id="project-title" class="text-input text-input--transparent item-title" rows="1" placeholder="Title" style="line-height: 1.4em; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; padding: 0; padding-right: 10px;"></textarea>
          </header>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col width="45px"> 
          <span class="item-label" style="padding-top:16px;"><ons-icon icon="ion-android-done-all" fixed-width="true" ng-style="{color: project.done  == 1 ? 'green' : 'grey'}" style="opacity:0.5;"></ons-icon> {{project.tasksDone}}/{{project.tasks.length}}</span>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="35px"></ons-col>
        <ons-col>
            <textarea ng-model="project.description" ng-blur="save($index, false)" class="textarea textarea--transparent item-desc" placeholder="Description" style="width: 100%; padding-right: 10px; margin-bottom:15px;"></textarea>             
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
```

Comment: Hey honk, you are completely right! I have added the code with the textareas. Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide your testing platform?

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't know what you mean by providing my testing platform.

Comment: Have you tested it only in Monaca or also on some devices? If yes, which os (Android, iOS etc.) and which version (Android 4.4.2, iOs 8.0 etc)? Please, nice that Monaca uses a webView based on iOS and the performances are not the same as a real device.

Comment: I have tested it with iOS and Android but the flickering is mainly in iOS and it is when a textarea is included within the page being transitioned.

Comment: Which Android version and which device?

Comment: Android 4.42 (Galaxy Note) and iOS 8 (iPhone 6), flickering occurs in iOS,what is  webView? Is there a way to debug the app in iOS in a different way than webView?

Comment: If I am right, phonegap uses webView too which is what my app will be based on.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just referring about Monaca's webView. I'll take a look at it when I'll have a little bit of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the body tag that I included in all the html files that caused the flickering. The body tag must be excluded from any template page but in the index.html. It now works smooth.